# Can / should I use the ranges library to emulate set functions?

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity, c++20, std-ranges

I want to apply a `view::filter` to a vector in order to find the set_intersection (or set_difference, etc) of it with another vector.

My interest in doing this is that it would allow you to alter a particular subset of the original container (and would also save on some of the copying that comes with `std::set_intersection`).

This is more or less what I want to do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> set1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                     set2 =          { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    auto intersection = set1 | std::views::filter([&set2](int n)
    { return std::find(set2.cbegin(), set2.cend(), n) != set2.cend(); });

    for (int& v : intersection)
        v *= 2;

    for (auto v : set1)
        std::cout << v << " ";   // prints 1 2 3 8 10 12
}
```

However, this code looks very inefficient, since it's going to iterate over set2 so many times. Is there a better way of achieving this with the `ranges` library?

Comment: You might want to construct an `unordered_set` from `set2` and capture that in your filter lambda instead.

Comment: Do you know both vectors will be sorted, as shown?

Answer (score 2):

> However, this code looks very inefficient, since it's going to iterate over set2 so many times.

It is inefficient, and also the approach isn't generally valid. In your example, the elements are all distinct. But what if they weren't?

```cpp
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 1, 4, 5 };
```

The intersection of these two should be `{ 1 }` but the approach of looking each element of `a` in `b` would yield `{ 1, 1 }`. Both of the other answers at the moment also have the same problem.

The easiest thing to do would be to use range-v3, which has far more range adapters than C++20. In particular, it has one named `views::set_intersection`:

```cpp
namespace rv = ranges::views;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b = {1, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << rv::set_intersection(a, b) << '\n'; // prints [1,3]
}
```

Which you can then use to alter the original container as desired:

```cpp
namespace rv = ranges::views;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b = {1, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int& i : rv::set_intersection(a, b)) {
        i *= 2;
    }

    std::cout << rv::all(a) << '\n'; // prints [2,1,2,2,6]
}
```

Note that only the first `1` is doubled.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I assume that you're talking about this library: https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/. What is its relationship to the ranges library in C++20?

Comment: @LiamGoodacre That's where the C++20 Ranges library comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, in the question, « to a vector », « of a vector » and « `std::set_intersection` » are considered important, I suppose we only want to deal with vectors (without transferring elements to another container) which are already sorted (as required by  [`std::set_intersection()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)).

I would use a mutable closure in order to alter its internal state from one iteration to another.
Then, we can use the same trick as in the [possible implementation of `std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection#Possible_implementation).
Since we always advance in `set2` (while the elements are considered *too small*) and never *look back*, the complexity is not similar to N1×N2 but to N1+N2 (as explained in [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection#Complexity)).

```
    auto intersection = set1 | std::views::filter(
      [b2=cbegin(set2), e2=cend(set2)](int n) mutable
      {
        while((b2!=e2)&&(*b2<n))
        {
          advance(b2, 1);
        }
        return (b2!=e2)&&(*b2==n);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put the set of values of `set2` into an actual `std::set`, so that checking if an element of `set1` is in `set2` is more efficient?

Doing so you can simply transform `set1` by returning unchanged those value that are not in `set2` and changing those that are:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> set1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::set<int>    set2 =          { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    auto set1edit = set1 | std::ranges::views::transform( // O(set1.size())
            [&set2 = std::as_const(set2)](auto const& x){
            if (set2.find(x) != set2.end()) // O(log(set2.size()))
                return x*2;
            else
                return x;
            });

    for (int const& v : set1edit)
        std::cout << v << " ";   // prints 1 2 3 8 10 12
}
```

Notice that I've highlighted that the complexity of the `transform` is O(`set1.size()`), as you process once each one of the `set1.size()` elements in `set1`; it doesn't even make sense to make `set1` a `std::set`, as a `std::vector` is just fine if we have to loop an all elements.

On the other hand, using [`std::set<>::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) guarantees a better performance than using [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

As implied by a comment, if you know that both vectors are sorted, then everything can be made easier, but I have the feeling that the sorted vectors in your example are just a consequence of an "excessive" simplification that you attempted.